# How do I get iCloud to share Safari tabs between devices?

Tags: icloud, safari

I'm logged into iCloud on two devices, an iPhone and my MacBook, but I only intermittently see a list of the Safari tabs I have open on one device on the other, and even then, they are generally out of date (often weeks old). Most of the time though, I see nothing:

[image]

How do I reliably get an up to date list of the tabs I have open on my other devices?

---

Devices in question are a MacBook Pro and an iPhone, all software is the latest (as of macOS 11.1, iOS 14.3) and this issue has persisted over years through reboots, migrations, updates, new devices, logins and logouts of my iCloud account, changes of location, etc.